# I'm trying to convert a keras transformer model to pythorch, but the number of model parameters are different

Tags: python, keras, torch, transformer-model

Why does the pytorch model only have ~3.7 million parameters while the keras model has over 30 million? Is there something that I did wrong or is there such a big difference beetween the keras and the pytorch implementation of the multiheadattention layer?

Is there a difference how keras and torch handles the sequential layer after the multiheadattention?

**Tensorflow**

```
def get_angles(pos, i, d_model):
    angle_rates = 1 / np.power(10000, (2 * (i//2)) / np.float32(d_model))
    return pos * angle_rates

def positional_encoding(position, d_model):
    angle_rads = get_angles(np.arange(position)[:, np.newaxis],
                            np.arange(d_model)[np.newaxis, :],
                            d_model)

    # apply sin to even indices in the array; 2i
    angle_rads[:, 0::2] = np.sin(angle_rads[:, 0::2])

    # apply cos to odd indices in the array; 2i+1
    angle_rads[:, 1::2] = np.cos(angle_rads[:, 1::2])

    pos_encoding = angle_rads[np.newaxis, ...]

    return tf.cast(pos_encoding, dtype=tf.float32)

class PositionEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, max_len, embed_dim):
        super(PositionEmbedding, self).__init__()
        self.pos_encoding = positional_encoding(max_len,
                                                embed_dim)

    def call(self, x):
        seq_len = tf.shape(x)[1]
        x += self.pos_encoding[:, :seq_len, :]
        return x

class TransformerBlock(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, rate=0.1):
        super(TransformerBlock, self).__init__()
        self.att = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
        self.ffn = keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu"), layers.Dense(embed_dim), ]
        )
        self.layernorm1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, inputs, training):
        attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
        return self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)

def transformer_classifer(embed_dim, ff_dim, max_len, num_heads, dropout=0.1):
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(max_len, embed_dim))
    transformer_block = TransformerBlock(embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim)
    embedding_layer = PositionEmbedding(1024, embed_dim)
    x = embedding_layer(inputs)
    x = transformer_block(x)
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 75, 768)]         0         
                                                                 
 position_embedding (Positio  (None, 75, 768)          0         
 nEmbedding)                                                     
                                                                 
 transformer_block_1 (Transf  (None, 75, 768)          31491584  
 ormerBlock)                                                     
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling1d (G  (None, 768)              0         
 lobalAveragePooling1D)                                          
                                                                 
 dropout_41 (Dropout)        (None, 768)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 32)                24608     
                                                                 
 dropout_42 (Dropout)        (None, 32)                0         
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 66        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 31,516,258
Trainable params: 31,516,258
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Pythorch**

```
class TransformerBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, max_len, rate=0.1):
        super(TransformerBlock, self).__init__()
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.max_len = max_len
        self.att = nn.MultiheadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, embed_dim=embed_dim, batch_first=True)

        self.sequential = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=embed_dim, out_features=ff_dim),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(in_features=ff_dim, out_features=embed_dim)
        )

        self.layernorm1 = nn.LayerNorm(normalized_shape=embed_dim, eps=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = nn.LayerNorm(normalized_shape=embed_dim, eps=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(rate)

    def forward(self, inputs, training=True):
        #print("inputs shape", inputs.shape)
        attn_output, _ = self.att(inputs, inputs, inputs)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
        seq_output = self.sequential(out1)
        seq_output = self.dropout2(seq_output)
        return self.layernorm2(out1 + seq_output)


class transformer_classifer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, ff_dim, max_len, num_heads, dropout=0.1):
        super(transformer_classifer, self).__init__()
        self.max_len = max_len
        self.transformer_block = TransformerBlock(embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, max_len)
        self.embedding_layer = PositionEmbedding(max_len, embed_dim)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(in_features=embed_dim, out_features=32)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=2)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
    
    def forward(self, inputs, training=True):
        x = self.embedding_layer(inputs, self.max_len, training=training)
        x = self.transformer_block(x, training=training)
        x = torch.mean(x, dim=1)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        #x = self.softmax(x)
        return x

================================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                                  Param #
================================================================================
├─TransformerBlock: 1-1                                 --
|    └─MultiheadAttention: 2-1                          --
|    |    └─NonDynamicallyQuantizableLinear: 3-1        590,592
|    └─Sequential: 2-2                                  --
|    |    └─Linear: 3-2                                 1,574,912
|    |    └─ReLU: 3-3                                   --
|    |    └─Linear: 3-4                                 1,573,632
|    └─LayerNorm: 2-3                                   1,536
|    └─LayerNorm: 2-4                                   1,536
|    └─Dropout: 2-5                                     --
|    └─Dropout: 2-6                                     --
├─PositionEmbedding: 1-2                                --
├─Dropout: 1-3                                          --
├─Linear: 1-4                                           24,608
├─ReLU: 1-5                                             --
├─Linear: 1-6                                           66
├─Softmax: 1-7                                          --
================================================================================
Total params: 3,766,882
Trainable params: 3,766,882
Non-trainable params: 0
================================================================================
```